# Python checking the parentheses are equal on both sides

Tags: python, find, position

I wrote a code but dont know how to make it find the extra unbalanced parentheses this is my code

```
def checkBalance(str1):
count = 0
for i in str1:
    if i == "(" or i == "{" or i == "[":
        count += 1
    elif i == ")" or i == "}" or i == "]":
        count -= 1
    if count < 0:
        return False and str1.find(")")
return count == 0 

str1 = input("Enter a string of brackets: ")
print("Given string is balanced :", checkBalance(str1))
```

For example if i input ()()() the code will say it is balanced but if i input something like this (())) it will say it is not balanced. what i want to add is that it would say code is balanced or not and says the first position of the side that is not balanced like ***CODE IS NOT BALANCED ")" POSTITION 3*** and i would like to do it for the other side aswell if it is not balanced ((()) ***CODE IS NOT BALANCED "(" POSTITION 1***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly wrote something that could sort your problem. Sorry for it being a little untidy. I made it a little more elaborate aswell (not mixing bracket types etc.).

The relevant parts, that I guess could have helped you a lot are the following:

- The enumerate function will let you iterate over something, giving both the value and the position of a given entry (here a tutorial example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/)
- f-strings are a great way to incorporate variables in your strings. Just put an f infront of your string and put your variables in curly brackets.

So if you want to try for yourself I would advise checking out enuemrate and f-strings. Otherwise you can use the below function.

```
def checkBalance(str1: str) -> str:
    """ Checks if there is unmatched brackets.
    
    :param str: The string that shall be checked
    ...
    :returns: A message detailing if and where brackets are unmatched.
    """
    
    brackets = {"curly": {"open": "{",
                          "close": "}",
                          "count": 0},
                "round": {"open": "(",
                          "close": ")",
                          "count": 0},
                "square": {"open": "[",
                           "close": "]",
                           "count": 0}
    }
    
    for pos, i in enumerate(str1):
        for bracket in brackets:
            if i == brackets[bracket]["open"]:
                brackets[bracket]["count"] += 1
    
                for name in brackets:
                    if name != bracket:
                        if brackets[name]["count"] != 0:
                            return f"Error, opening {bracket} bracket before {name} bracket shut at position {pos}."
    
            if i == brackets[bracket]["close"]:
                brackets[bracket]["count"] -= 1
                if brackets[bracket]["count"] < 0:
                    return f"Error, closing {bracket} bracket at position {pos} without opening bracket"
    
    return_val = ""
    for name, info in brackets.items():
        if info["count"] > 0:
            return_val += f"You have {info['count']} unmatched opening {name} brackets \n"
    
    if return_val != "":
        return return_val
    
    return "No problems with your brackets."
```

Comment: The code does exactly what I wanted but now I will simplify the code to my experience because no way in the world I would write something like that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In every iteration, the innermost bracket gets replaced with empty string. If the final string is empty, its balanced otherwise not.

```
def checkBalance(check_string):
    brackets = ['()', '{}', '[]']
    while any(item in check_string for item in brackets):
        for br in brackets:
            check_string = check_string.replace(br, '')
    return not check_string
   
str1 = input("Enter a string of brackets: ")
print("Given string:", str1, "is", "Balanced" if checkBalance(str1) else "Not balanced")
```

Comment: although this works as intended and my original code did the same, but it did not tell the position of the first extra one for example if i write (() it would say not balanced and write postion 1 because this is an extra ( at start and if i write (())) it would say not balanced because extra ) in 3rd position. i want to use find or count but not sure how to add it so i probably need to write the whole code again.